# SQL - PHPmyadmin - Alter table order by 'id ascending' - Make permanent

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

If I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `equipos11a12` ORDER BY  `ID`
```

It only happens one time. If I change the ids, it wont change in ascending order.

I have to run the alter table everytime in order for the ids to order.

Here is my php code:

```
 $query = "SELECT  * FROM equipos11a12";

$result = mysql_query($query);  ?>

while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo " " . $person ["name"] . " ";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the order by clause to your select query :

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM equipos11a12 ORDER BY `ID` ASC"; // ascending order    
$query = "SELECT  * FROM equipos11a12 ORDER BY `ID` DESC"; // descending order
```

Comment: thnx! but, how do i select which...like ascending or descending?

Comment: juste add ASC or DESC to the order clause, I'll update my answer.